# Python exp operation for matrices

Tags: python, matrix, exponential

I have a matrix

```
x=np.mat('0.1019623; 0.1019623; 0.1019623')
```

and I want to find the exponential of every element and have it in a matrix of the same size. One way I found was by converting to array and proceed. However, this won't be a solution if we have, let's say, a 2x3 matrix. Is there a general solution?

Comment: Have you tried `np.exp(x)`?

Comment: Thank You! The problem was that I was importing from math rather than numpy.

Comment: Save yourself some hassle and don't use `numpy.matrix` objects. `numpy.array` has far fewer weird inconsistencies and incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with me using `math.exp` instead of `np.exp`.